# How to get jQuery autocomplete selected values as an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using **jQuery autocomplete** multiple select, I'm trying to get the values into an array like: ["kiwi", "fraise", "avocat", "banane"], however it is only showing as: kiwi, fraise, avocat, banane,
I'm using chosenjs along with the chosen.order plugin
As I said I can easily get the selected items in order, I just can't get it to output as an array, any help would be most welcome.

The jquery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Chosenify every multiple select DOM elements with class 'chosen'
$('select.chosen').chosen();

// Get a reference to the DOM element
var MY_SELECT = $('select[multiple].chosen').get(0);
    $('#get-order').click(function() {
    var selection = ChosenOrder.getSelectionOrder(MY_SELECT);      
    $('#order-list').empty();
    $('#order-list').html("<div>" +  selection + "</div>"); 

    });

  });
```

And the HTML is:

```
<h1>The Chosenified multiple &lt;select&gt;</h1>
<p>
<select name="fruits" class="chosen" multiple style="width: 500px;">
    <option value="banane">Banane</option>
    <option value="pomme">Pomme</option>
    <option value="poire">Poire</option>
    <option value="ananas" selected>Ananas</option>
    <option value="kiwi" selected>Kiwi</option>
    <option value="goyave">Goyave</option>
    <option value="abricot">Abricot</option>
    <option value="fraise" selected>Fraise</option>
    <option value="framboise">Framboise</option>
    <option value="avocat" selected>Avocat</option>
 </select>
 </p>

 <h2>Retrieving the order</h2>
 <p>
<button type="button" id="get-order">Retrieve selection in order</button>
<br/>

</p>
<P>
<div id="order-list"></div>
```

Comment: the selection-variable is actually an array. i've tried it with your code. test it with `console.log(selection);`

Comment: Your absolutely right, i never thought of that, thank you

Comment: although, it adds spaces at either end like;

Comment: [ "kiwi", "fraise", "avocat", "banane" ] rather than ["kiwi", "fraise", "avocat", "banane"]